# Dependency injection vs singleton, Initialization

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I'm working on a big project right now, and the app is taking advantage of many different services, as:
Comments, likes, posts, purchase and so on..

I have a class for each service.

Now, I came to a point where I would like to restrict registered users only, for some actions, as post, comment, and so on..

Till now every class use to have only class methods, as the following:

```
 @interface UpdateOrderServies : NSObject

+(void)deleteOrder: (STOrder *)order
         andReturn: (void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;

+(void)updateOrder: (STOrder *)order
         andReturn: (void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

But now, i would like to check first if the user is registerd, and if not, not to return a value.
So the best way i figgerd out is changing the classes to singel tone, and asking every time the class is called, if the user is registerd like so:

```
+(id) getInstance {

    static UpdateOrderServies *__sharedDataModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedDataModel = [[UpdateOrderServies alloc]init];

    });

    if (![__sharedDataModel userIsRegisterd]) {
        return nil;
    }

    return __sharedDataModel;

}
```

And it works, but, well, its not a very good answer as you can see.. i would like somthing more generic.
I was thinking about using Typhoon dependency injection, but there is no place were i could check every call if the user is registered...
Any idea for a better way to deal with this issue? more dynamic...

Comment: Why not identify users, when they first "log on" or otherwise identify themselves, with a "capability" object which encapsulates all their authorizations, etc.  Use that instead of a simple user ID to identify the user, and query that object to test user's abilities.

Comment: @HotLicks "Why not identify users when they log on" . . that step is authentication. Next is to define what permission is required to invoke a given service - this part is called authorization. We could authorization as part of each service call, but that would break the single-responsibility principle - hence recommend AOP.

Comment: @JasperBlues - You place the "responsibility" in the user's capability object.  The capability must be presented to perform an authorizeable operation.  That seems like a "single responsibility" scheme to me.

Comment: @HotLicks The capability object is, but what about performing authorization - ie evaluating the capability object? As that is a 'crosscutting' requirement it must be repetitively applied. In fact security is a common example when explaining AOP. (I'm sure others could do a better job of explaining it than me). . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: AOP has always been a solution in search of a problem, and I don't see how this is it.  The capability object encapsulates whatever is needed to either retain authorization info or access it when called upon.  It is a single point of control with a single responsibility.

Comment: @HotLicks "AOP has always been a solution in search of a problem" - not the history of AOP *at all*. Contributors recognized as top 100 innovators in computing, hundreds of books from reputable authors on the topic, etc. Your opinion is bold! Without method interception, show how you can authorize many service invocations from a capability object without modifying each the services. You can't! At best you need a single line to ask your capability object "can i proceed". The only argument is whether this is a fair compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question above, I think you're not looking for dependency injection but Aspect Oriented Programming.

Aspect Orientes Programming (AOP) is designed to solve exactly the kinds of problem you describe above - those that cut across many modules in your system. Examples:

- *every time* a user interacts with a service, security should be checked.
- *all transactions* should have an audit trail
- *every store interraction* should result in a genius recommendation

If we use normal Object Oriented programming for these cross-cutting requirements, we break the *single responsibility principle* and a class that should've been nearly about one topic is now taking on more roles which gets confusing, repetitive and messy.

AOP modularizes these cross-cutting concerns and then identifies all of the places these should be applied using *method interception*. (In AOP we call this a point-cut expression).

In Objective-c you could either do manual AOP using ISA-swizzling, message forwarding or or using NSProxy - these are all ways of achieving method interception at run-time. Alternatively, you could use a library and one such library called '[Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects)' by Pete Steinberger and team. This library doesn't have a point-cut expression language as yet, but is still certainly much simpler than using the ObjC run-time directly to intercept methods.

**Summary of how an Authorization Aspect would work:**

- At login we authenticate our user, using a username/password challenge, oauth token or similar. Having authenticated a user we are now able to authorization service invocations.
- Identify each of the services that require authorization, and the required permission (you can whatever scheme you like roles, capabilities, etc).
- Good Object Oriented principles say that each class should have a single responsibility. So your service client should be all about invoking the remote service. We could edit the service client to evaluate the logged in user's permissions and decide whether to proceed. But this would be messy and repetitive. Instead we'll use the information in step 2 (permission required for each service) and delegate that evaluation of that to our authorization module.
- ***Now the AOP step:*** For each service call, we'll tell our AOP lib to intercept service client method and first invoke the authorization module.

This way your *cross-cutting* requirement (authorizing client invocations) isn't repeated. Now you may to decide for the sake of simplicity that you can prefer with having each service call invoking an authorization module, but it nonetheless helps to know the theory behind AOP and cross-cutting concerns.

**Dependency Injection / Typhoon**

Dependency injection doesn't really relate directly to your question, though it can certainly help to avoid the pitfalls of your singleton clients:

- Creates a clear contract between your classes - increasing code cohesion.
- Identify the key 'actors' in your application, and describe the way they are assembled into a whole. Makes it possible to swap one actor for another that will fulfill the same contract.
- Simplifies unit testing using mocks and stubs.
- Simplifies integration testing - being able to swap one actor for another to put the system into the required state. For example, patching out just an authorization module.